# Command Block : Testing For Entities

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This might not be possible, but i wanted to see if anybody had an answer before i tried something else.

So in one of my worlds, i have a Minecart Command block which, gets triggered as it rides round a track, but is there a way to actually Test For it existing?

I have tried `/testfor @e[type=MinecartCommandBlock]`

But it just outputs`[00:44:19] Unknown command. Try /help for a list of commands`. When it works just fine in the in-game console:
`Found entity.Minecart.Command.Block.name`

Does anybody know a way to solve or know of a way around this?

Comment: are you sure you typed the command in the command block correct?

Comment: The command i used in the post is exactly what i put into the command block.

Comment: It should work fine. Make sure you are copying the command correctly (no spaces before).

Comment: I checked, no extra spaces, no other characters or misspelled words. I just don't understand i have been trying to figure it out for about an hour and a half.

I have had a similar problem before, just like this where the command block just would not accept the command, in the end i just left it.

Comment: does the time change as you excecute it?

Comment: the testfor command doesn't give an commandblock console output as it seems

Comment: Well, my initial idea was to get a command block to detect for a Minecart commandblock in the world, then get it's output if true, to be used to light up a red stone lamp. But if that doesn't work, I dont know of a way around it.

Comment: + I noticed that actually the time doesn't change, but i still don't get an output.

Comment: [It's working fine for me, command blocks and chat](http://i.imgur.com/apajQbr.png). I get the "entity.MinecartCommandBlock.name" thing, but it still detects it. So long as you're actually activating the command block, and you're sure that you have typed it correctly, then I have no idea.

Comment: @EpicMineC Are you 100% sure that you are activating the command block? It sounds like you may not be. If it's a minecart, check that you're using a **powered** activator rail, and not a detector rail. If it's on a /fill clock, make sure it is actually running. If it's on a comparator clock, make sure the command block is far enough away to be properly unpowered then powered.

Comment: I found the solution, The game for some reason, wasn't detecting that it was being powered (idk how) i restarted my client went back into the word and now it woks fine, (entity.MinecartCommandBlock.name) i knew there wasn't a problem with the actual command. Thanks all for helping me find the solution to my problem.

Comment: @EpicMineC Please submit as the answer that worked for you.

Comment: This might sound stupid but, How do I do that?

Comment: @EpicMineC, underneath this comment (scroll down to the bottom of the page), there's a large text box. Write your answer into there.

Comment: Cant Find it, I have look around the page but cant find a place to answer

Comment: @EpicMineC Click the button that says "Answer Your Question".

Answer (score 1):

This command should work. If the time is always the same in the output and  doesn't change, the command might be succeeding but not outputting to the console. Try using a comparator directly next to the command block to check whether it is finding the Minecart Command Block. If the comparator is lit, the command is succeeding. If the comparator is not lit, the command is either incorrect or the block could not find the entity you're looking for. If it continues outputting

> [00:44:19] Unknown command. Try /help for a list of commands

then try opening the command block, pressing CTRL + A to highlight all, then pressing CTRL + C to copy. Next, break the block and place a new one, then open this new block and do CTRL + V to paste. Sometimes when I have this problem it helps to "reset" the block in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the appropriate name of the block/item **dependant on your Minecraft Version**.

## Minecraft 1.11 and Later

Now, I'm going to *assume that you are using the newest version yet*, Minecraft 1.11.2 .
If so, perfect.

You'll want to modify your command so it looks a bit like this:

> /testfor @e[type=Commandblock_minecart,r=5]

The Radius-Parameter *isn't necessary*, but useful for when you are in an area hosting many Command-Block-Minecarts (As you'll be able to detect and maybe get rid of the ones you don't need with the Radius-Parameter).

The:

> type=Commandblock_minecart

... bit, is to specify that It Is Indeed a Command-Block-Minecart; the new ID was introduced in the early 1.11 Release (Snapshot 16w32a), because... well, Mojang haven't specified a reason yet, but it's assumable that it's to prevent typos.
Link to the Gamepedia-Wiki page on it:  [Command Block Minecarts](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecart_with_Command_Block)

(Note: that the capitalisation of 'Command' is in place by standard. If it does not work for you, change the first letter to a lowercase 'c'. That goes for all items/blocks referenced in commands.)

## Minecraft 1.10 and Versions Before

If your version is, as said above, 1.10 or before, you'll have to use the original in-place name for it:

> MinecartCommandBlock

... and in a /testfor command:

> /testfor @e[type=MinecartCommandBlock,r=5]

Again, *the Radius-Parameter isn't necessary*, I regularly insert them for clarity and by-tradition.

(Second Note: The ' /testfor '-Command is only present in Minecraft Versions 1.5 (Snapshot 13w03a) and Higher!)

## Summary

In short, different names are used to improve readability, portability and general mark-up.

' *commandblock_minecart* ' for Minecraft 1.11 and Later,

whilst,

' *MinecartCommandBlock* ' for Minecraft 1.5 to 1.10 .

I hope my answer has helped solve your conundrum.